# Supersized plugin disables Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, supersized

I am creating a website based off Bootstrap's basic marketing site: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html
However when I install the Supersized jQuery plugin it disables my dropdown menu.
Can anyone tell me how to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried switching the link order in your html. Place supersized.js first or vise-versa

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Supersized version 3.2 and jQuery version 1.9.

try by including jQuery migrate plugin (  http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/)